# Unable to sent email in java application deployed in azure

Tags: java, azure, email, clout

we have a java application which we have deployed on the azure cloud. The email sent functionality is working fine before the deployment on azure. But when we deployed the application on azure the functionality is not working.
We have done two step verification in the google account for local machine and virtual machine too. But on the virtual machine or azure cloud these functionality is not working. Anyone do have solution for this please help me out. Thank you in advanced!!!!

Answer (score 1):

**short answer:the port 25 was blocked by Azure.**

This is in place to prevent abuse of the service and stop spammers etc.

> For all examples below, the process applies only to Virtual Machines & VM Scale Sets resources (Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines & Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets). Sending email on Port 25 is unsupported from all Azure Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS) resources, including Azure App Service and Azure Functions.

Check this article for detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity

Comment: Is their another way to overcome to this issue?